# Android viewing transfered image

Tags: android, image, file, sockets, android-sdcard

Im making a client application for my ZTE Blade Android phone, which receives a image file from a PC through a socket. The problem is that when I have saved it to my SD card through the application and want to view it, the image is just black for about 40 seconds, then it appears. If I try again later, it still takes that long. If I restart my phone, the problem is gone.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: You'll have to post some code of how you save and how you load. I would ask if you close the file once you have finished saving it to the SD card (it could cause the file to be in an open status that android automatically times out after 40 sec)

Comment: Thanks for your help:), but I found it now, I had to refresh the SD-card. Using a sendBroadcast method worked http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8d4ee33849c2e774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it seems like I needed to refresh the SD-card. [This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8d4ee33849c2e774) used a sendBroadcast method which solved my problem.